# How to Render Components to react-sidebar main content view

Tags: reactjs

[dashboard][1]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sidebar from "react-sidebar";
import Main from '../util/dashboard/Main';
import Users from './Users';
import Pages from './Pages';

const sideBarMenu = (
<div>
    <div>
        <NavLink to='/show' >
            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" width="140" />
        </NavLink><br />
        <p>ID 113350 </p>

        <div>
            <div>
                <p className="color-green o-sidebar-header">TRANSACTION</p><br />
                <ul className="o-nav-ul">
                    <NavLink to="/main"><li  className="color-white">Main</li><br /></NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/users"><li className="color-white">Users</li></NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="Pages"><li className="color-white">Users</li></NavLink>
                </ul>
            </div><br />             
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

)

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
state = {
sidebarDocked: mql.matches,
sidebarOpen: false
}

render() {
return (
    <div>

        <Sidebar
            sidebar={sideBarMenu}
            open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
            docked={this.state.sidebarDocked}
            onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
            styles={{sidebar: { background:"#290c49"} content:{background:"#f5f5f5",marginTop:"5px"}}}> 

            <Main  />

        </Sidebar>
    </div>
        )
    }
```

}

I am using react-sidebar package. I have been trying to find how to display different components to the contents(Right side of the sidebar menu) on click of a menu on the sidebar menu list.

Currently, from the code sample the 'Menu' components is displayed. How do i display any other component in place of the 'Main' component.

]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9GYv.png

Comment: it depends ... usually common parent, redux store, state ... more details needed, show some code - structure of components, routes ... and describe your expectations

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited the question a bit to include  some of the things you highlighted.

Comment: why not use `<Link/>` and different route?

Comment: Using Link will route to a new component all together replacing all contents including the sidebar and sidebar menu

Comment: thats why I asked for details - exact use case, what you need ... why replacing content isn't suitable .... details plz

Comment: @samuel The react-router docs include a sample of a sidebar in combination with react-router (navigating via Link component) https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar

Comment: @xadm it made no sense to me to add the sidebar together with its menu and contents in all components I want to render to the view. That's why i cant simply replace all the contents, the sidebar menu should remain. I want one sidebar, one sidebar menu where all other components I intend to render to the view display as the sidebar's main content.

Comment: @sn42 Thanks, I've looked at it before. I will have to go that way only if there's no way to achieve what I intend. Which is kinda disappointing cause one would expect a sidebar to have support for rendering different components to its main content view

Comment: Do you need to insert entire layout to content component when you need to render content in layout? When it appears that sth has to be repetited it's time to decompose/destructure it into separate components. When both content and sidebar are childs/siblings you need to use parent to pass data/value otherwise it would breake top-down data passing rule. Component is responsible for own content - you can tell him what to render but not render content for his element - his next render call would remove 'external' changes. You have to think in react/component way, not by html/nodes/jquery...mess.

Comment: @samuel As you see there is a bit of confusion about what you want to do. In my view your explanations in the previous comments don't help much and more or less increase the level of confusion, because in one comment it sounds like you just want a basic sidebar where u can select the page to display next to it and in another comment it sounds like you want to render multiple components simultaniously in the main content component. This confusion wont be solved in comments. Add some GUI sketch maybe or some Code to your question which might clarify your intent pls.

Comment: @sn42 Thanks. You are right, my comments have been quite misleading, much to my chagrin. All I want is the basic sidebar as you earlier mentioned. I have added some more code which is just a bit more from what was there before. This is basically all the code on my sidebar. I just need to know how to render different components to the content view of the sidebar. Which is the fundamental function of a sidebar in the first place

Comment: @xadm you appear to have misunderstood me. I have edited the question I really hope you understand what I intend to achieve.

Comment: @samuel I'm really struggling to understand then where you have problems with. I've put up [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mo3ko99959) with react-sidebar and react-router-dom, does this help you or can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: @sn42 I just saw the example and it solved the problem. Not sure why I didn't think of it in the first place. Thanks so much

Comment: @xadm thanks a lot for your answer. Your approach is basically same as  the  [link example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mo3ko99959) by sn42 the only difference been BrowserRouter Component was added as the direct parent of the Switch. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need sth like this?

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar
        sidebar={sideBarMenu}
        open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
        docked={this.state.sidebarDocked}
        onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
        styles={{sidebar: { background:"#290c49"} content:{background:"#f5f5f5",marginTop:"5px"}}}> 

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Main}/>
          <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
          <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
        </Switch>

      </Sidebar>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Of course this doesn't mean that `<Sidebar/>` renders sth in content placeholder. Sidebar content and main content are rendered as siblings - they are connected by parent. `react-sidebar` hides this complexity.